# JSON in HTML escaping

Tags: javascript, html, json, encoding

I'm including JSON in an HTML tag, considering the only possible input characters for the JSON will be `"':{},[a-z][0-9]` is it possible for JSON or HTML to be broken with my approach? What should I be wary of when using JSON across HTML and Javascript?

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?=htmlspecialchars(json_encode($myArray));?>" />
```

Comment: JSON allows for JS strings, which can include the HTML/SGML/XML special characters `<`, `>`, `&` (and `"` and `'` if used in HTML attributes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSON](http://www.json.org/) can contain nearly any character in its strings. As you are using it in an attribute, <s>`escape_quotes`</s>`addslashes` should be enough, that depends on your (X)HTML version. `htmlspecialchars` is OK anyway.

Comment: this one? http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php someone said don't escape single quotes for JSON. Why wouldn't you want to do this?

Comment: You're right, thanks. You don't need to escape single quotes, only when you use them as HTML attribute delimiters...

Answer (score 1):

in the [definition of json](http://www.json.org/), one of the posible values its a string. which can contain `<`, `>` among other things

you can use a base64 enconding to avoid this.

Comment: May be a good idea to use urlsafe base64 if you base64 it. ( base64 with - instead of + and _ instead of /, optionally with padding dropped ) to avoid the text being encoded.Probably not required, but would save some space with the text.

Comment: AFAIK urlsafe its not standard, and its more complicated to get encoder/decoder. but i may be wrong